# Help to make my table view-able kind help

Tags: tables, longtable

I am a fresher to latex

```
\begin{landscape}
\caption{Large table}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$\\ \hline
$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$\\ \hline
$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$\\ \hline
$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$\\ \hline
$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$\\ \hline
$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$\ldots$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$&$0123456789$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
```

each inside has `$0123456789$` ten characters in maximum some do have less in each `$$` area.
 there are 7 rows and 20 columns.

Kind help

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. What are you hoping to achieve by bombarding your readers with 7*20=140 numbers, each of which may contain up to 10 [!] digits? Are your readers supposed to memorize all of them? Should they maybe take note of just 2 of the numbers? Then show those 2 numbers -- *and no others*. If you do have to show all 140 numbers, do consider either transposing the entire table (so that it has 20 rows and 7 columns) or breaking it up into 4 smaller tables, each containing "just" 5 columns.

Comment: Respected sir,   I have some research  terms and information to be put in table which values I cannot reveal so only put dummy data to get the understanding of how to manage a table whose maximum size is as above

Comment: Please rest assured that even before you posted your follow-up comment, I was already pretty sure that your plan was *not* literally to typeset the string `0123456789` 140 times. :-) My comment, then, was not about the actual values of the 140 numbers; instead, it was about the aim or purpose of showing 140 numbers at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove as much space as you can:

- Remove space to the left and right of the `tabular`/`array` using `@{}`.
- Remove vertical lines.
- Make the inter-column space as small as possible using e.g.

  ```
  \arraycolsep=2pt
  ```

Then make the font as small as necessary/possible, using e.g. `\tiny`.

It the table is still too large, use the `adjustbox` environment defined in the package of the same name to shrink the table to the size needed.

Finally check whether the result is still readable. Maybe it is better to split the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{sideways}
  \begin{minipage}{\textheight}
    \captionof{table}{Large table}
    \tiny
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
    $\arraycolsep2pt
     \begin{array}{@{}cccccccccccccccccccc@{}}
     \toprule
       0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     \\\midrule
       0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     \\\midrule
         \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     \\\midrule
       0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     \\\midrule
         \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots   &   \vdots
     \\\midrule
       0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 &   \cdots   & 0123456789
     & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789
     \\\bottomrule
     \end{array}
    $
  \end{adjustbox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: who can read this table? someone with hawk exes? I suggest to transpose table and than use normal size fonts.

Comment: @Zarko Well, maybe the OP wants to print on microfilm, then these letters are still huge ... My last suggestion in the post is exactly to check for readability. But if we need to print 20 x 10 characters in a row, with some space inbetween, than this is what we get ...

Comment: transposing of table is OP  consideration and job :). are people today still use microfilms?

Comment: @Zarko. Don't know, was rather meant as a joke. It seems that it is still used for archiving documents, since it is longer lasting than digital documents.

Comment: my response is also rather joke ...